# Display results if null or not. SQL

Tags: sql, interbase

I have two tables, `ingredient` and `ingredient_language`.

I need to display (from SQL) all translations of each ingredient, and in case that I did not have any translations for some language, in the rows have to appear like this, for example:

```
Language | Ingredient
ENG        Salt
GER        NULL
```

How can I display it?

The structure of the tables are

```
Ingredient{id_ingredient}
Ingredient_Language{id_ingredient, id_language, traduction}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT i.id_ingredient, l.id_language, l.trad
FROM Ingredient i
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Ingredient_language l ON l.id_ingredient = i.id_ingredient
```

[image: Example]

Okey, the structure are:

```
·Table 1 (Ingredient) > Columns: Id_ingredient (PK), standard_name
·Table 2 (Language) > Columns: ID_Language (PK), name_language 
·Table 3 (Ingredient_Language) > Columns: ID_Ingredient_Language (PK),ID_ingredient (FK), ID_LANGUAGE(FK), description
```

Example of data (Can not do any screen at this moment):

```
 ·Table 1: 01, Orange
 ·Table 2: SP, SPANISH
           ENG, ENGLISH
 ·Table 3: 01, 01, SP, Naranja
```

What I need to get? The following example:

```
Header: id_language, id_ingredient, description
Row1:      SP            01            NARANJA
Row2:      ENG           01              NULL
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are looking for an outer join

Comment: do you have a language table?

Comment: "*did not work*" is not a valid error message (and not an acceptable problem description). Also: do **not** post code in comments. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35199228/edit) your question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will try to do best: My problem persists because in that case when I try to do with an outer join, my query only displays the ingredients (with traduction) that i have in ingredient_language, not in both.

Comment: Again: **edit** your question and add the query you are using.

Comment: i repeat my question: 
 
do you have a language table?

Comment: You have some basic problem - do you want the language or the ingredient as the basic data? If it is the language than start your join from the language and not from the ingridient.

Comment: Just a tip, name the table `ingredients` (plural, for several rows with ingredients), and the column `ingredient` (singular, for one ingredient).

Comment: Singular table names are common practice, a table nearly allways contains multiple rows so there is no sense in plural naming.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Tarsis I Tryed with your last edit, but having the same problems.  I am using Interbase

Comment: Sorry i am not going to do any more guessing, if you need help give proper information: post the structure of all 3 tables including at least some rows of data so we can understand what a join will actually do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start with a cross join, which combines every ingredient with every language:

```
SELECT i.id_ingredient, l.id_language, il.trad
FROM Ingredient i
CROSS JOIN Language l
```

and add all existing translations to that with

```
LEFT JOIN Ingredient_language il 
   ON  il.id_ingredient = i.id_ingredient 
   AND il.id_language = l.id_language
```

if you have a database which does not support `CROSS JOIN` you can try

```
SELECT i.id_ingredient, l.id_language, il.trad
FROM Ingredient i
JOIN Language l ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN Ingredient_language il 
   ON  il.id_ingredient = i.id_ingredient 
   AND il.id_language = l.id_language
```

Comment: Can not do a Cross Join in Interbase

Comment: Working. Amazing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.traduction,l.id_language,i.id_ingredient 
FROM Ingredient_Language AS l 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Ingredient AS i ON l.id_ingredient = i.id_ingredient
```

Just change the SELECT part to your needs.

Just a guess, you might actually wanna begin the join from your language table like

```
SELECT l.id_language,i.id_ingredient 
FROM Language l
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Ingredient_Language il ON l.id_language = il.id_language 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Ingredient i ON li.id_ingredient = i.id_ingredient
```

Comment: Continue with the same problems. Only shows ingredient with traduction but not where traductions are pending.

Comment: Please give some example Data of both tables